# What does one look for to increase conversion rate of landing pages?

Tags: landing-page

I'm about to create several landing pages. I'm trying to find methods or means to produce the highest conversion rate possible.

What could someone do to increase ones conversion rate for a landing page?

I'm looking for an answer that has experience, references, or metrics to back up their claim. I know a lot of this is an art.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some research and found some things. I ended up doing an [extensive blog](https://globerunner.com/ultimate-guide-to-high-converting-landing-pages/) on this as well. I put in the findings below as well:

## Anatomy of a Landing Page

[Source](http://web.archive.org/web/20150213202842/https://www.formstack.com/the-anatomy-of-a-perfect-landing-page)

[image]

## Resources

- [Landing Page Best Practices](https://vwo.com/blog/landing-page-best-practices/)
- [Search Engine Land: How To Create High-Converting Landing Pages](https://searchengineland.com/how-to-create-high-converting-landing-pages-39593)
- [Landing Page examples](https://vwo.com/blog/landing-page-optimization-tips-increases-sales-conversions/)
- [Search Engine Watch: The Art of the Landing Page: 7 Tips For Increasing Conversions](https://searchenginewatch.com/sew/opinion/2048835/the-art-landing-page-tips-for-increasing-conversions)
- [Search Engine Watch: 5 popular tips could hurt your conversions](https://searchenginewatch.com/sew/opinion/2101606/popular-landing-page-optimization-tips-hurt-conversion-rates)

## Using Belcher Button:

- Vidler video on "http://www.viddler.com/explore/tacvideos/videos/69/":http://www.viddler.com/explore/tacvideos/videos/69/

## Examples of one page landing pages

- [PageMako](http://www.pagemako.com/index.php)
- [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/login?cont=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.dropbox.com%2Fteam)